# Disable nasty pseudo-error message in solium

Tags: solidity

Solium treats now `require` without error message as error that obviously incorrect. I have a lot of `require` inside my contract and do not want  to garbage it with disabling comments. In the same time I cannot find how to disable message `error-reason: Provide an error message for require().` completely through `.soliumrc`.

I added this line to my project's solium config without any results:

```
"error-reason": {"enabled": false}
```

Comment: if solium is a part of bigger tool like Solidity for VS Code it maybe be should be done other way try inline to check if it works

Comment: @XaweryWiśniowiecki you are right. I found that adding file to `.soliumrc` doesn't affects VSCode, it is managed by its own settings file. After adding same switch there damned warning disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for [Solidity for VS Code](https://github.com/juanfranblanco/vscode-solidity#linting) says "...soliumrc.json support will be included in the near future, for specific project linting requirements". At the moment you can configure your linter using VS Code [configuration file](https://github.com/juanfranblanco/vscode-solidity#linting):

```
   "solidity.linter": "solium",
   "solidity.soliumRules": {
       "quotes": ["error", "double"],
       "indentation": ["error", 4]
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `"error-reason": "off"` into `.soliumrc.json` file.

Example:

```
{
    "extends": "solium:all",
    "plugins": ["security"],
    "rules": {
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "double"
        ],
        "indentation": [
            "error",
            4
        ],
        "linebreak-style": [
            "error",
            "unix"
        ],
        "error-reason": "off"
    }
}
```